# Minikube networking

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a Linux build machine that I have installed minikube too. Within the minikube instance I have installed artifactory which I will be using for storing various build artifacts

I now want to be able to do some work on my dev machine (which is an unrelated laptop on the same network as the Linux build machine) and push some built artifacts into artifactory.

However I can't figure out how to get to artifactory. When I ssh to the Linux server and check the minikube service I can see that the artifactory instance is running on a 192.168 address.

Is there any way to expose artifactory ie access it on the windows machine? Or is this not possible and I should just install artifactory on the Linux machine rather than in minikube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we need an ingress controller (like nginx) to expose a kubernetes service for external access.

There are three ways to create the nginx ingress service using kubernetes per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types and expose it for external access:

1. `LoadBalancer` service type which sets the ExternalIP automatically. This is used when there is an external non-k8s, cloud-provider's load-balancer like CGE, AWS or Azure, and this external load-balancer would provide the `ExternalIP` for the nginx ingress service.
2. `ExternalIPs` per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips.
3. `NodePort`. In this approach, the service can be accessed from outside the cluster using NodeIP:NodePort/url/of/the/service.

Along with the nginx ingress controller, you'll need an ingress resource too. Refer https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example for examples.

Keep in mind that Minikube is a small VM with a small docker registry by default. So, it may not be possible to store a lot of build artifacts in Minikube.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is what I did in the end really with nginx as a reverse proxy. Good point on the vm disk size though I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Sykomaniac glad to help, upvote my answer if you think it is useful!

Comment: @aerokite we can use `NodeIP:NodePort` or `ExternalIP:Port` to access the service from remote.

Comment: When you are using minikube, did you check that? Minikube runs in a virtual network. Host IP is also virtual.

Comment: Yes, when using Minikube, we need to add the required route from the laptop to the Minikube VM or to the ingress if nginx ingress controller is used.

Answer (score 4):

Expose you artifactory Service

```
$ minikube service <artifactory-service> -n <namespace>
```

Or get the URL

```
$ minikube service <artifactory-service> -n <namespace> --url
```

If you want to access from remote, you need to do something else.

Suppose, when you run `minikube service <artifactory-service> -n <namespace> --url`, you get following

```
http://192.168.99.100:30654
```

You can access artifactory in minikube using this URL. But can't access from remote.

Now do this, expose port **30654**

```
ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:30654:0.0.0.0:30654
```

You will be able to access from other network.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have done this but as I said it's only available on a 192.168 address. I assume this is to do with the minikube setup.

Comment: What do you mean by expose? Do you want to access from remote? or from local?

Comment: From remote. I want to be able to access something running in minikube (which is on a Linux machine) on my windows laptop that is on the same network but a different machine.

Comment: Can you try added solution?

Comment: Thanks for this. Probably a silly question but what would the ip address be that I need to hit? Would this be the ip of the Linux machine that minkube is running on? Just asking as I can't test just yet but will do tonight.

Comment: Do you have any dedicated public IP?

Comment: No I don't I'm afraid. The windows machine and the Linux machine are on the same network e.g 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. The minikube server is exposing services on 192.168.x on the Linux machine. I want to be able to hit that address from the windows machine. If that makes sense!

Comment: try to hit `127.0.0.1` with port

Comment: I will try that. But won't that only work on the Linux machine? How would the windows machine be able to resolve the port on localhost?

Comment: Also check hitting `10.0.0.2`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks I will give it a try tonight!

Comment: yes it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help. One other question is there a way of keeping the connection open without me having to keep the ssh session alive?

Comment: You need to setup your physical router to set port forwaring

Comment: Hi.. you can add `&` at the end of `ssh`. Like `ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:30654:0.0.0.0:30654 &`

Comment: This will run in background

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work in the end I setup ingress on minikube and then through entries in hosts file and nginx as a reverse proxy managed to get things working.